# "I live on beans and rice" vs. "I live off beans and rice"

Tags: meaning, differences

I wanted to refocus a [related question on ell.se.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17938/i-dont-understand-live-off) towards a possible deeper and direct relationship to "on vs. off".

Consider the following two phrases:

- I [live off beans and rice.](https://www.google.com/search?q=lives+off+rice+and+beans&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS550US550&oq=lives+off+rice+and+beans&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3j69i65l2.3273j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=%22live+off+rice+and+beans%22)  (Approx 94,000 results Google Search)
- I [live on beans and rice.](https://www.google.com/search?q=lives+off+rice+and+beans&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS550US550&oq=lives+off+rice+and+beans&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3j69i65l2.3273j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=%22live+on+rice+and+beans%22)  (Approx 67,000 results Google Search)

In addition to the subtle difference in meaning, I'm particularly interested in where the semantics of the differences might come from.  Can we trace the semantic difference between "live on" and "live off" to a fundamental, "definitional" aspect of "on vs. off"?

---

*Below, I've answered my own question as an afterthought.  It was additional thoughts that needed to be moved to an answer, and is in no way intended to be definitive.*

Comment: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/live+on http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/live+off

Comment: I don't think one lives *off* beans and rice.

Comment: live *off* beans and rice - is actually *more popular* on Google search.

Comment: @Kris, Thanks for the comments. I've updated the question with links to google results which shows "live off" is slightly more popular than "live on" in this case. (A gross "google search comparison" certainly doesn't prove anything, and I'm not refuting you. But had it been an order of magnitude difference, I would have pulled the question.) Thanks for the links I'll check them out!

Comment: I think "live off beans and rice" is more popular because it may have multiple meanings. It may mean "I make a living selling beans and rice".

Answer (score 3):

After reviewing some anecdotal examples, I'm proposing a possible answer, called  **On vs. Off: The Zombie vs. Leech Theory of Grammatical Usage<sup>1</sup>** .  "On" seems to have a connotation of active and pursuing while "off" seems to have a connotation of passive or required.  (The other usage is the literal, location-oriented definition.)

---

**PART 1:  Zombie Vs. Leech Theory**

The following is the most vivid example of Zombie Vs. Leech:

- "He feeds off his parents." (He's a leech.)
- "He feeds on his parents." (He's a zombie.)

What's the difference between a zombie and a leech? Here are a few anecdotal examples:

- "He lives on/off campus." (Location oriented.)
- "He lives on the campus." (Location oriented.)
- "He lives off the campus." (Ambiguous. Similar to "lives off the land". Could be location oriented.)
- "He lives on his parents."  (Absurd.  Literal parsing is like "stands on his bike." Since that's not plausible, most people would likely reinterpret this as "lives off". Thus this would be leech because zombie doesn't make sense.)
- "He feeds on excitement."  (He seeks excitement. perhaps he creates it. Similar to the zombie interpretation.)
- "He feeds off excitement." (He's more passive. he likes excitement given to him. he may instigate people to argue either with himself or each other. it thrills him passively.  More like the leech interpretation.)
- "He lives on rice and beans."(It might be volitional. maybe that's his diet. Zombie)
- "He lives off rice and beans."(It's the way he survives.  Leech.)

  ---

**Part 2: Knowledge Influences Semantic Interpretation**

I need to get closer to the "ground of meaning" of the words "off" and "on".  Here are some more simple and (relatively) objective scenarios.

- The cup is on the table. (This contains an assumption. The cup must have been **actively** put on the table.  It wasn't on the table before.)
- The cup is off the table. (While this suggests that the cup [was on | might have been on] the table, it is **passive** in one sense: the cup never *had to be* on the table for it to be off the table.
- She put the cup on the table. (**Active Placing. Movement Towards. "To there" Bringing Together.**)
- She took the cup off the table. (**Active Retrieving. Movement Away. **"From there"**. Bringing Apart.**)
- He lives on the apple tree. (Ambiguous. He could have a tree house or uses the apple tree for food.)
- The monkey lives on the apple tree. (Semi-ambiguous. One might prefer the "house" concept since we quickly think of monkeys living in trees.  There's cognitive dissonance on the word 'on', but that could be "excused" in favor of a stronger semantic result.)
- The giraffe lives on the apple tree. (Non-ambiguous. We know giraffes do not live in trees. The giraffe eats apples or leaves.)
- He feeds on the apple tree. (He goes **to there** and eats, perhaps without even removing the apples! Biting the tree might even kill it. Zombie-like behavior.)
- He feeds off the apple tree. ("Off" is "retrieving". Bringing Apart. More likely that the apples are "taken off" the tree.  Tree is likely to live.  Leech-like behavior.)
- He lives off the land. (Under most contexts, the location aspect doesn't make sense. Location-wise, everyone "lives off the moon" so why even mention it?  He retrieves life sustenance from the land.)
- He lives on the land. (Semi-Ambiguous.  One might imagine a man standing on some land.  Then maybe building a house or tent.  But if he's **"living on the table"** he must be spending quite some time there so obviously he needs to get his food there too.   Also, it's odd to state the obvious (most everyone "lives on land"), and it's idiomatically similar to the prior sentence. So it can be substituted for the prior.  It can also have a broader meaning: not only retrieving sustenance, but also spending much time there.)

<sup>1</sup> Disclaimer: This post is a *very informal exploration* of an idea.  This is "original content" in the wikipedia sense:  It's not based on anything other than my own thoughts, and surely suffers any and all bias that comes with that.

Comment: I'll upvote this because *in some circumstances* the distinction you make can apply. But in practice most people would either use *to live **on/off** [some single source of sustenance]* interchangeably, or they would have an (effectively meaningless) personal/dialectal preference for one or the other.

Comment: Also note that Google Internet "guesstimates" can be even more misleading than those for Google Books. But there's no doubt that, for example, the idiomatic [*live **on** thin air*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22live+on+thin+air%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is more common that the ***off*** version by a couple of orders of magnitude. But that directly contradicts your final two examples. In the final analysis, there probably *is* no meaningful analysis.

Comment: Note: FumbleFingers "final two examples" refers to "final two examples **of Part 1**.  I have added **Part 2** which may explain some things in terms of how reality-fitting could affect a preferred interpretation.

Comment: Well, [the evidence suggests](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=live+on+the+interest%2Clive+off+the+interest&year_start=1930&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clive%20on%20the%20interest%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clive%20off%20the%20interest%3B%2Cc0) that Americans today are more likely to *live **off** the interest [generated by their savings]*, rather than ***on** it*. And Brits are rapidly moving towards that preference too. But I don't believe for one moment they meant something different, back when everyone always used ***on*** in that context.

Comment: Well of course they meant something different! The attitude of "living on interest" back then couldn't be the same as now. An excerpt from "The Quintessence of Capitalism"(Sombart, 1930): *"The bourgeois waxes fat as his riches increase and as he accustoms himself to live on the interest of his capital, to be held in the vice of luxury..."* Changing attitudes can be reflected even in subtle shifts in language. Maybe even from "on to off". Today we've integrated the metaphor: plant your money, grow it, live off the interest (like living off the land). Not proof, but not unreasonable either.

Comment: If you think that I don't see any prospect of me changing your mind. But so far as I'm concerned, you could just easily reverse **on/off** in your examples and it would make absolutely no difference - there's nothing "reasonable" about your position that can't be "reasonably" countered from the opposite perspective.

Comment: @FumbleFingers let's slow down! I tremendously appreciate your feedback. I'm multidimensional and the brevity of comments prob makes me sound one-sided and I can't say caveat caveat caveat and every damn smile looks the same --> : ) <-- . I'm the "Zombie vs. Leech" guy remember? Who relates grammar to Zombies and Leeches? I'm not arguing a stance; I'm exploring an idea. Your experience far outweighs mine. I'll review your reverse on/off = same thing idea. Seriously, thanks again for your time and effort replying.

Comment: Okay - sorry if I was getting a bit "shrill" by the end there. I started by upvoting your comment because there can sometimes be an undeniable rationale as to why one idiomatic preposition wins out over another. But often it's little more than "post hoc" reasoning. There's a limit to how far you can take the idea that English might be "logical" (basically, *on average* it just ***ain't*** :)

Answer (score 1):

My simplistic answer.

**He lives off his parents.** He is not gainfully employed and is financially supported by his parents.

**He lives on his parents.**  He is some kind of parasitic organism that physically infests his parents and/or feeds on them. Maybe this is possible in biology, I don't know.

**He lives on beans and rice.**  He survives on a diet of beans and rice.

**He lives off beans and rice**.  He he earns his money from the production and/or marketing of beans and rice.